# Create a series of PowerShell variables from Excel to execute in Robocopy

Tags: excel, powershell, variables, robocopy

[image]

Using the PowerShell module importexcel I have created the variables and the job is running but with a few caveats. The data from the source is dumped into the root of the destination (which is expected based on the variables I've created - which is one of many areas I ask for help).

```
$dataJob01 = Import-Excel "C:\temp\test.xlsx"


ForEach ($project in $dataJob01){
    $source = $($dataJob01.Source)
    $destination = $($dataJob01.Destination)

    robocopy $source $destination /e /copy:DATU /dcopy:DAT /log:C:\temp\log.txt
}
```

1. Is there a way to append the "Folder Name" to the destination variable? Making the `$destination = \\server2\share\PROJECTS\304401`

Until the issue in problem 1 is solved, problem 2 is irrelevant but ideally I want the job to process 100s of lines below the excel snippet above. Unfortunately, that is failing with the code I've written. It's as if the source and destination are being bunched together vs. being processed on each line. I thought `ForEach` was appropriate but I'm a noob.

2. When I run this against multiple lines, I receive no output and the job fails.

Hopefully I'm not going about this the wrong way and someone has some pointers for me.

Comment: The `ForEach` creates a `$project` variable, but it is never used. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Is there a way to append the "Folder Name" to the destination variable? Making the `$destination = \server2\share\PROJECTS\304401`

Here you can use `Join-Path` which works perfectly for what you need:

```
$destination = Join-Path $project.Destination -ChildPath $project.'Folder Name'
```

I've noticed you're using `$dataJob01`, which is the array you're using to iterate, inside your `foreach` loop. Try using this instead (I changed the name of the variables, so it helps you understand. `$line` is exactly that).

```
$xlsx = Import-Excel "C:\temp\test.xlsx"

ForEach ($line in $xlsx)
{
    $source = $line.Source
    $destination = Join-Path $line.Destination -ChildPath $line.'Folder Name'

    robocopy $source $destination /e /copy:DATU /dcopy:DAT /log:C:\temp\log.txt
}
```

Comment: I just stumbled across this but wrote it out slightly different `$destination = -join ($($project.Destination),$($project.'Folder Name'))` but robocopy seems to have omitted the files and only pulled over the directories. Thank you as this was very helpful and seems cleaner with your approach. Now to battle robocopy. Thank you

Comment: @mrn3ff no problem, i'm happy it worked for you :)

Comment: @mrn3ff the reason why `$destination = -join ($($project.Destination),$($project.'Folder Name'))` was not working is because you're creating an `array` instead of a `string`. If you were to use the `-join` operator in this case, you could do `$destination = $project.Destination, $project.'Folder Name' -join ''` considering that `$project.Destination` ends with a backslash ```\``` but it is 100% recommended to use `Join-Path` because it avoids possible misakes :)